# How to execute two python functions in parallel on Linux？

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here are two methods `f_1` and `f_2` to solve the same problem.
These two methods run in **in parallel on Linux**, execution time of both is limited to 10 seconds. I want to terminate the other process when one returns a result.

```py
import random
import signal
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event


class Alarm(Exception):
    pass


def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Alarm


def f_1(event):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    signal.alarm(10)
    try:
        d1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 20))
        d2 = time.time()
        event.set()
        print("f_1 cost: %.4f, result: %i" % (d2-d1, 1))
        return 1
    except Alarm:
        event.set()
        print("f_1 time out!!!")
    return 0


def f_2(event):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    signal.alarm(10)
    try:
        d1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 20))
        d2 = time.time()
        event.set()
        print("f_2 cost: %.4f, result: %i" % (d2 - d1, 2))
        return 2
    except Alarm:
        event.set()
        print("f_2 time out!!!")
    return 0
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("task 1")
    d1 = time.time()
    functions = [f_1, f_2]
    event = Event()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=functions[i], args=(event,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
    # terminate the other process when one stops
    while not event.is_set():
        pass
    for p in jobs:
        p.terminate()
    d2 = time.time()
    print("total cost: %.4f"%(d2-d1))
    sys.exit(1)
```

I wonder why the other does not terminate when one returns a result in my implementation and why the print of f_1 always appears before f_2. I just need the first result!
I will be very grateful If there is a better way to attack this parallel problem. Thank you very much!!

Output:

> task 1
> f_1 cost: 5.0040, result: 1
> f_2 cost: 9.0092, result: 2
> total cost: 14.0223

Comment: `p.join()` *waits until the process finishes* - you aren't actually running anything in parallel here.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your comment! I have changed the position of `p.join()` in the question above.  I wonder whether `p` will be a zombie process after I remove `p.join()`.